# QML: Button in footer unresponsive when using ListView.OverlayFooter

Tags: qt, listview, qml

**EDIT :** The issue seems to be related with Qt 5.15 and does not show up with Qt 5.14 !

I'm learning QML and made an app composed of a Window containing a ListView.

I'm trying to add a Button, which should be at a fixed position at the bottom of the window (it shouldn't move when I scroll). Thus, I decided to add this Button to the footer attribute of the ListView, and set footerPositioning: ListView.OverlayFooter

However, doing so makes the button totally unresponsive.
If I comment out the footerPositioning line, the button works as expected, but is wrongly placed.

The documentation states that "*If footerPositioning is not set to ListView.InlineFooter, the user cannot press and flick the list from the footer. In any case, the footer item may contain items or event handlers that provide custom handling of mouse or touch input*" ; which to me doesn't say that the item (here a button) event handling shoudn't work.

Here is an exemple of code that shows the unresponsive button behaviour :

Debug.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.9
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.9

Window {

    visible: true
    width: 260
    height: 520

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        spacing: 6
        model: 4

        delegate: RowLayout {
            width: parent.width
            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                height: 60
                color: "#ff0000"
            }
        }

        footerPositioning: ListView.OverlayFooter // comment out this line to make the button responsive
        footer: Button {
            height: 180
            width: 90
            background: Rectangle {
                id: backbtn
                color: "gray"
            }

            onClicked: {
                backbtn.color = "#00ff00"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Debug.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

How can I make the button responsive while keeping ListView.OverlayFooter ?

Comment: I have tested your code - it seems to work fine. The button changes its color from _gray_ to _green_ when clicked.

Comment: How did you run it ? I'm adding my main.cpp to the question then

Comment: Created new project in Qt Creator, copied your code, run it. Do you expect any other action than that color change?

Comment: Color change is the only expected action. I created a new project and pasted my code again, problem is still there.. What could cause the difference in behaviour we have ? I'm using MSVC2019 64 bits with Qt 5.15 in Debug configuration

Comment: That's interesting. I was testing using MinGW 7.3 and Qt 5.14 and it worked. However, with MSVC2019 and Qt 5.15 it does not work for me too.

Comment: There is such a bug reported:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85302
Maybe you will find it interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the bugreport, that's precisely my problem! What's the conduct to follow on SO when your issue is in fact a bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is bug-related, as identified by Thomenson. In Qt 5.15, using a ListView with clip enabled and ListView.OverlayFooter seems to disable mouse event handling in the footer.

Switching from Qt 5.15 to Qt 5.14 fixes the problem.

The bugtracker to the related issue can be found here : [bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85302](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85302)

Answer (score 0):

We can't downgrade so until [QTBUG-85302](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-85302) is fixed workaround is to set `clip: false` for the `ListView` and `clip: true` for the parent container item: `Rectangle` or `Item`, which has same size.